# Jackrabbit RMI lucene conflict

Tags: java, lucene, jackrabbit

I wish to integrate with **Jackrabbit 2.x** in my application for versioning of data.

My application has a dependency on **Lucene 2.9.1**

The problem is that Jackrabbit is dependent on a **higher version** of Lucene (**3.6**) and as a result I can not place the `jackrabbit-core` jar in the same classpath as my application as it conflicts with my lucene jars.

Seeing as I prefer not to implement a WebDAV client I thought about using the RMI implementation, however, I see that the `jackrabbit-rmi` jar is also dependent on `jackrabbit-core` and Lucene.

Is there any way to work around this to use jackrabbit RMI in my application? or is there some other solution that will allow me to use Jackrabbit without upgrading my lucene jars?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to repackage newer Lucene into another package and use it from there.

Comment: the problem is that my version is older. Also packaging won't solve the problem of referencing both jars in the same classpath, if I include the 'new' packaged jar with my own I will still have a conflict with the other dependencies.

Comment: If it's only your own code which requires new Lucene, then it should be ok as you would be referring to the newer Lucene API via different package. But if these are some other libraries that require newer Lucene, then I don't think jarjar or any other tool could help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about configuring Jackrabbit as a Ressource provider in your application server ?
Thus you would reference it via JNDI and only via the JCR API avoiding the conflict (since the ressource would be in a different classloader).